# How to use <Subscription /> component with initial query?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

The docs show an example where you start listening to new data with the  component, but how would you do an initial query before listening for new data?

Answer (score 0):

If your initial query differs from subscription you should probably use `<Query />` component and use `subscribeToMore` function for subscription.

Docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more